# parent div width in firefox and opera is 0 even if i have childs

Tags: javascript, css, html, width

I have a div with no width set, so it's 0. Inside i appended another div with a text. Everything is set absolute and i can't change that. What happens is: in safari i get 30 and 30, in firefox i get 0 and 30.
Is there any way to solve this? I need that my parent div width to have the width of the child + it's x position.

```
var d = document.createElement("d");
    d.style.position = "absolute";
    document.body.appendChild ( d );

    var c = document.createElement("s");
        c.style.position = "absolute";
        c.innerHTML = "Blah";
    d.appendChild ( c );

    console.log ( d.scrollWidth );
    console.log ( c.scrollWidth );
```

Answer (score 2):

If both elements have to be set to position: absolute then you're pretty much out of luck.

Using absolute positioning removes the element from the document flow, which means that the parent div has no concept of the width of the child div. If you change the child to relative while leaving the parent as absolute, then you'll see the correct stretching that you want (since the parent will be able to "see" the child even though the rest of the document can't "see" the parent)

Comment: I was afraid of that, seems i have to do my own calculations.